# How good was Voldemort at reading minds?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

From Ch - 1 of GoF, Voldemort is quoted as:

> "You have no wife", said the cold voice, very quietly. "Nobody knows
>   you are here. You told nobody that you were coming. Do not lie to Lord
>   Voldemort, muggle, for he knows.. he always knows.."

As Dumbledore says in the third book that Divination is a very difficult art, and he also considers a raise for Prof. Trealawney just for her second correct prediction in years.

So, how good was Voldemort at that art? Or is it just due to a background check on the Riddle House, or just a speech of grandeur?

---

Related discussion: [How good was Lord Voldemort at Divination?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117740/53012)

Comment: What does Divination have to do with anything in that chapter?!?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _for he knows.. he always knows.._ sounded more like the art of Divination to me :)

Comment: Divination is about seeing the _future_. Knowing when someone is lying to you is an entirely different set of skills, more along the lines of mind reading (which is what Legilimency is to minds that “lack subtlety”, as Snape describes Harry).

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but I wonder, how good *was* Voldemort at Divination? Are there any canonical examples?

Comment: @ibid That is the question being asked...

Comment: Something tells me you haven't got to book 5 yet, @Dawny33...this is why I warned you last time these questions lead to spoilers :P

Comment: @DavidS haha I have a horde of doubts in a notepad for asking after finishing the books. This however, couldn't wait :D

Comment: @Mithrandir no one is going to give any answers to this question not focused on the OP's quote.

Comment: @ibid Even I was interested in the same. However, my perception of the quote was wrong. Anyways, I have asked a separate qn abt the same [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117740/53012)  :)

Comment: I daresay Dumbledore may not be 100% serious when thinking aloud about the pay rise for Trelawney.

Comment: @chirlu Even I thought he was being sarcastic. But, if you read the chapter properly, he was fairly impressed  by Professor Trelawney. And he explains how difficult divination is, too.

Comment: So wait - Trelawny had been working there for years as the professor of Divination, despite only having successfully done it *once* before in her entire career?  I get that it's difficult, but if teaching it is someone's entire job, you'd hope they'd had at least a *little* more experience than that?  Firing her might've actually been the right move - she should never have been hired in the first place...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Divination can be about gathering information generally, in its historical guise.  The future is very popular, of course, but usually scrying, farseeing, dowsing, reading palms or auras, or other means of viewing the present or past are also included under its wide banners.  in HP, there is an emphasis on seeing the future, yet it doesn't exclude the other meanings - crystal balls might equally show present or past, and palm reading is personality, not really future.  Some definitions might include Harry's visions, or even Legilimancy as forms of divination.

Comment: Well, clearly he could be deceived. Severus Snape hid the fact that he was not the master of the Elder Wand, and Harry Potter hid the fact that he WAS the master of the Elder Wand - although both might well have been well-skilled in Occlumency. Narcissa Malfoy lied to him about Harry's death. So it's obviously do-able...although it's probably not one could fail at and get a second chance.

Comment: 5. Voldemort was 5 good at legilimency.

Comment: As Himarm said, Voldemort _was_ a great Legilimens; however it's likely that he didn't need that skill in the particular occasion, but simply knew beforehand that Frank Bryce wasn't married. He surely wasn't so dumb not to let Wormtail do some reconaissance work before putting up tents in Little Hangleton.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's actually Voldemorts impressive skill at Legilimency, according to Snape in *OotP*:

> “The Dark Lord is highly skilled at Legilimency —”
>
> “What’s that? Sir?”
>
> “It is the ability to extract feelings and memories from another person’s mind —”
> He smirked. “It is true, however, that those who have mastered Legilimency are able, under certain conditions, to delve into the minds of their victims and to interpret their findings correctly. The Dark Lord, for instance, almost always knows when somebody is lying to him. Only those skilled at Occlumency are able to shut down those feelings and memories that contradict the lie, and so utter falsehoods in his presence without detection.”

Comment: Might be worth adding where that quote is from and who is talking - that's a conversation between Snape and Harry in the Order of the Phoenix.

Comment: In his conversation with Bellatrix at the beginning of _Half-Blood Prince_, Snape calls Voldemort *the most accomplished Legilimens the world has ever seen*. While this is in favour of his argument at the time, Bellatrix doesn’t seem to disagree.

Comment: The young Tom Riddle was already very advanced in this art, and actually shocked when it didn’t work on Albus Dumbledore: *‘Tell the truth!’ He spoke the last three words with a ringing force that was almost shocking. It was a command, and it sounded as though he had given it many times before. His eyes had widened and he was glaring at Dumbledore, who made no response except to continue smiling pleasantly. After a few seconds Riddle stopped glaring, though he looked, if anything, warier stil. ‘Who are you?’*